# Redirect to another site with not standard port (IP:Port)

Tags: php, html, redirect, port

How can i Redirect to another site with not standard port (IP:Port) on Php or Html?

On php i try to use header('Location: IP:PORT' ); but it doesn't work.

Any tips to fix this?

Comment: `header('Location: http://IP:PORT');`?

Comment: It works for me without `http://` too. What do you mean, not works?

Comment: you need to use a proper url: `Location: protocol://host:port/path`

Comment: Yes the syntax is that but doesn't work. When i call the page it remains in load state

Comment: Then you can't reach that IP from your computer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a proper absolute URL:

e.g. you're on "example.com", and want to redirect to "example.net":

```
header('Location: example.net:443');  // redirects to http://example.com/example.net:443
header('Location: http://example.net:443') // redirects to the url as written
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `http://` <s>or `//`</s> in front of the address to tell PHP that it is an absolute URL.

For example, if you wanted to redirect to `123.123.123.123` on port `8888`, you would do something like this:

```
<?php

header('Location: http://123.123.123.123:8888');

?>
```

#### Note:

> <s>It is usually recommended that you use `//` and not specify `http://` explicitly.</s>

Using `//` makes sense<sup>(only?)</sup> when loading HTML resources. For example,

```
<script src="//foobar.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

The `Location` header, however, accepts an absolute URI. ([See specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30))

Comment: It is recommended to use `//`? Any confirmation on that? Using `Location` header without the protocol is what's against the specification.

Comment: `//` is recommended for resources defined in html, for a header redirection I would properly use `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].'//123.123.123.123:8888');`

Comment: The value of `Location` consists of a single absolute URI. See [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)